# How to modify object property in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Trying to create a really simple redux todo, almost there but got stuck on one thing.

```
export const completeTodo = (todo) => ({
  type: 'COMPLETE_TODO',
  data: {
    name: todo,
    complete: !todo.complete
  }
})
```

however, struggling to get the reducer working as I can't work out how to determine the exact object im working on

reducer:

```
case 'COMPLETE_TODO': {
   const chore = { ...state.chores, complete: action.data.complete}
   return { ...state.chores, chore };
}
```

and initialState is:

```
const initialState = {
  chores: [{name: 'cleaning', complete: false}]
}
```

obviously when i click my button is should be wired up so it can change the complete boolean to the opposite but only for that one todo

Comment: Either identify the todo based on its index in the array, or give it a unique ID and search the array for that. Have you read the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/)? It shows exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an array you need to replace it with a new one

```
case 'COMPLETE_TODO': {
      return {
        ...state,
        chores: state.chores.map(chore => 
         chore.name === action.data.name
         ? {...chore, complete: true /* or !chore.complete if you want toggle like behaviour*/}
         : chore)
      };
    }
```

and in your action creator

```
export const completeTodo = (todo) => ({
  type: 'COMPLETE_TODO',
  data: {
    name: todo.name // assumning names are unique
  }
})
```

Comment: this is what I thought but it's not toggling it or throwing an error :/

Comment: @TheWalrus Glad I could help. Actually I have a typo in my code it should be `complete` not `completed`